# Brand new iPad Pro -- forces update to iOS 17.0.3 and fails every time

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update, data-transfer

I'm attempting to transfer my ipad to my brand new iPad Pro.
Whenever I try to transfer it gets to a state where the it installs iOS 17.0.3 -- there doesn't seem to be a way around the update -- and then it just hangs.

I've tried this 4 times now.

It's a super slow (huge update) on my 500Mbps network connection.

Look at how terrible the update screens look. Very unprofessional:

[image: 20 minutes - huge download for update]

Even after the download completes, then the "Download..." text fades but then it is "Preparing Update" for like 20 minutes.

[image: text overlaps on update screen]

Finally, you'll see this ridiculous screen:

[image: software update wait cursor forever]

Maybe I have a defective unit or something?
It's brand new out of the box.

Anyone else seeing these problems?

**Update**

After 45 minutes of the wait cursor and nothing happening, I turned it off and back on.

Then I saw the following:

[image: reconnecting...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never was able to do the transfer
Instead I had to set up the iPad Pro manually
Once the iPad started up it offered an update to iOS 16.7 — not 17.0.3

Now I’m going to see if there is a way to transfer my original iPad to the pro

**Update - Definitive Answer**

I finally figured out what the problem was with the transfer.

I wiped the new iPad Pro and tried the transfer again because I wanted my new iPad to be an exact replica of my old one and that is the only way to do it.

Anyways, as I ran the transfer, every time it had failed I had opted out of setting up Siri.

The screen is the one that asks you if you want to set it up now or ignore for later. It's something like this one:

[image: siri not now]

Previously (every time the transfer failed) I had chosen "Not now".

For some reason, this time when I attempted the transfer-setup, I chose the option to set up Siri.

When I did, the iPad Pro instantly flashed to the transfer screen (this time it did not require me to install 17.0.3). It took 3-5 minutes and my iPad transferred with all my apps and content.

That fixed it!  Very odd.